# How do you log in with a external database in Spring Security 6?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

after researching a few hours I couldn't find anything on how to log in when you are using a external database that contains the credentials in Spring Security 6.

```java
package de.gabriel.vertretungsplan.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/vertretungsplan").hasAnyRole("SCHUELER", "LEHRER", "VERWALTUNG")
                        .requestMatchers("/account").hasAnyRole("LEHRER", "VERWALTUNG")
                        .requestMatchers("/administration").hasRole("VERWALTUNG")
                        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin();
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

This currently is my SecurityConfiguration but I can't figure out how to retrieve user information and compare it with the username and password. In my [last project](https://github.com/github-gabriel/spring-security-applications/tree/main/JPA%20Authentication) I used a UserDetailsService like this

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}
```

but the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is outdated so I want to use the new method, which I guess, also uses a UserDetailsService in some way, but I just can't find anything on the internet. I [read](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider) [some](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) [articles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration/index.html) and watched [some](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfaQp3OS5yI) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9O9NI-RJ3o), but I can't find anything, which is why I wanted to ask here if someone knows how to use the external db for login (and yes, the entity that I am using has no relationships inside the db, if that matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bean implementing UserDetailsService in which you inject a DAO (Repository, ... as you like) that connects to the external DB configured by specific properties (login, password, url, ...) will do the job. You don't anything complex to retrieve user information, a basic JdbcTemplate in the DAO will do the job.

Comment: Yeah thanks, this suprisingly worked. I think I overcomplicated the problem, because I really only needed that bean and 2 lines of code and now it works, so thank you. It's just hard finding anything now because it is so new but your little manual helped me ^^

Comment: Sorry to disturb you, but now I wanted to ask how to do this for multiple UserDetailsServices (multiple Users). I tried it with multiple beans of which every bean is implementing UserDetailsService but that doesn't work, it gives me the error ```No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken```. But if I only have one bean implementing the UserDetailsService (doesn't matter which one) it works.

Comment: Yes the error is misleading: you get "no provider found" when in fact they are too many. But I don't follow your "(multiple Users)": a UserDetailsService don't care about the number of users in the repository. Or do you mean you need  several DB sources, cascading from one to the following until the user is found or all sources have been queried?

Comment: If the latest is your idea, then you have to create a "CascadingUserDetailsService" that should be the only UserDetailsService scanned as a bean but with knowledge of the other ones which of course should not be but in a Spring-scanned package... (you can use META-INF/services to declare them and discover them with ServiceLoader if you don't want to hardcode them in your application...)

Comment: I meant I have multiple different entities so I also need a different repository for each entity. And because I have multiple entities I need different UserDetails, which is why I also need different UserDetailsServices. And I now tried to create 3 different beans for the 3 different userdetailsservices I need for my 3 different userdetails which I need for my 3 different entities

Comment: I don't see the relation between "different entities" and the need of different UserDetails. You may need different UserDetails only if you have different datasources for your users, with maybe different access or availability rules. E.g. a LDAP for physical users and a DB for technical (processes, ...) users.

Comment: Really? I don't really get how to then. If I have 3 entities, schueler, lehrer and verwaltung how do I for example return the password. One UserDetailsImplementation can for example ```return lehrer.getPassword``` but what about schueler and verwaltung? How should I return their credentials? As of my understanding ONE UserDetails Implementation is for ONE Entity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250317/discussion-between-p3consulting-and-gabriel).